# JAVA OOP inheritance tree

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, tree

Pretend we have 5 classes or interfaces: U, G, B, Z and X, each type has his variable:

```
U u;
G g;
B b;
Z z;
X x;
```

this will compile:

```
u = z;
x = b;
g = u;
x = u;
```

this wont compile:

```
u = b;
x = g;
b = u;
z = u;
g = x;
```

**tree solution:**
[image]
**question: why is the G an interface and not abstract class?**
**also can G and X be both interfaces?**

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). I don't see how this question could be anything but a homework question, unless Lowie is in the habit of writing brainteasers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the `G` an interface and not `abstract` class?

Because `U` can extend exactly one class (`abstract` or not). Since `X` is a (`abstract`) class, then `G` must be an interface.

> Can `G` and `X` be both interfaces?

Yes. Java allows classes (like `U`) to implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: Not exactly, every class (except Object), must extend other class.

Comment: @amit: that is nonsense. Every class does automatically extend another class, if you don't specify one, it's by default the Object class.

Comment: @Stultuske Exactly, you extend Object. If your world has only 5 non primitive types, `X` must be Object, or something that extends it, so it's a class. The fact that there is a **syntatic sugar** that automatically says `extends Object`, is not saying it is not extending anything.

Comment: @amit: no, it doesn't have to be. public class U implements X, G{ is equal to: public class U extends Object implements X, G{. So, both X and G can be interfaces, not a problem.

Comment: @Stultuske and which of G,X,Y,B,Z is Object? You assume you are allowed Object to be out of this hirerchy - which seems foolish to me.

Comment: @amit: read my previous reply. neither G, X, Y, B or Z is or has to be Object. You assume that each hierarchy will include each and every class and interface that exists within Java and that is used. This would, in most cases, make the  trees way to complex to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

Why it is an interface? most likely because X is a class, and your U class can only extend 1 class.

Can G and X both be interfaces? Maybe, depends on the contents and how it's supposed to be used.
If it contains implemented (non-default) methods, and has to be able to be initialized on it's own, no, it won't be an interface.